# Toggle between partially opaque and completely visible of linear layout

Tags: android

**What i am trying to do:**

- I have a linear layout
- I am using `alpha` to validate the opacity
- I am trying to toggle between `partially opaque` and `not opaque`

---

**What is happening:**

1. I am able to set partially opaque using code

   linearLayoutView.setAlpha((float) 0.4);
2. Then i am setting not opaque using code

   linearLayoutView.setAlpha((float) 0.0);

But when i toggle back from partially opaque to noopaque .... color is dull(some of alpha state is retained)

***HOW TO RESOLVE THIS !***

Answer (score 1):

### Actually i was setting alpha values incorrectly, I modified code as

**I am able to set partially opaque using code**

```
linearLayoutView.setAlpha((float) 0.4);
```

**Then i am setting not opaque using code**

```
linearLayoutView.setAlpha((float) 1);
```